# Python: urlopen not downloading the entire site

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

Greetings,

I have done:

```
import urllib

site = urllib.urlopen('http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Temple+TX+76504')
site_data = site.read()
site.close()
```

but it doesn't compare to viewing the source when loaded in firefox.

I suspected the user agent and did this:

```
class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; zh-CN; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8"

urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()
```

and downloaded it, but it still doesn't download the whole website.

Can someone please help me do user agent switching, if that is the likely culprit?

Thanks,
Narnie

Comment: it works for me, i get ~100kB html data using the original example. btw, what do you mean by *whole website* ?

Answer (score 3):

It's more likely that there is an `iframe` in the code or that javascript is modifying the DOM.  If theres an iframe, you'll have to parse the page to get the url for the iframe or just do it manually if it's a one-off. If it's javascript, I hear that selenium-rc is good but have no first hand experience with it.

Comment: Why did this post get downvoted? Is it because I forgot to put the 'is' between 'selenium-rc' and 'good'?

Comment: not likely (.. iframe ..) , if you actualy look at the code :)

Comment: still, that and javascript are the first things to rule out in cases like this. I'm not going to sift through 100kb of (probably) badly formatted html - that's OP's job and  (s)he did nothing to indicate that that had been done.

Answer (score 2):

downloaded page displayed locally may look different from several reasons, like that there are relative links (can be fixed adding e.g. `<base href="http://www.weather.com/today/">` into the page head element), or non-functional ajax requests (see [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)).